# MySQL SELECT sytax error inside IF statement

Tags: mysql, select, syntax, if-statement, syntax-error

I am stuck in a MySQL syntax error and I really have no idea where the mistake is. I am executing a rather huge SELECT statement consisting of several different `select_expr` subselects:

```
SELECT
`a`.`id` AS `id`,
`a`.`name` AS `name`,

/* ... */

IF(((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `position` WHERE (`auftrag_id` = `a`.`id`) AND (`status` < 100)) = 0 ), ( To_days(SELECT `enddatum` FROM `position` WHERE (`auftrag_id` = `a`.`id`) ORDER BY `enddatum` DESC LIMIT 1) - To_days(`a`.`datum`) ), NULL) AS `days`,

/* ... */

FROM
`auftrag` `a`
```

The `select_expr` causing the error is the IF-statement inbetween, the rest of the whole statement works very well. The error output is:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT `enddatum` FROM `position` WHERE (`auftrag_id` = `a`.`id`) ORDER B' at line 50
```

What's the problem here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(unrelated): The `IF` you have is not a statement, it's a function.

---

Put the `SELECT` subquery:

```
To_days( SELECT `enddatum` 
         FROM `position` 
         WHERE (`auftrag_id` = `a`.`id`) 
         ORDER BY `enddatum` DESC 
         LIMIT 1
       )
```

between parenthesis:

```
To_days( ( SELECT `enddatum` 
           FROM `position` 
           WHERE (`auftrag_id` = `a`.`id`) 
           ORDER BY `enddatum` DESC 
           LIMIT 1
         )
       )
```